# Reduce the output with bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to run a basic bash program with two outputs, the program works and the tests passes. The thing is I want to reduce the output with only one "echo", when there's an input, show One for "input" and when is empty, One for you. This works but I want the out put in one line.

```
if (($# == 0)) 
then
    echo "One for you, one for me."
else
   echo "One for $1, one for me."
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want shorter code, this may help:

```
other="you"; [[ $# -ne 0 ]] && other="$1"
echo "One for ${other}, one for me."
```

The first line defaults the `other` variable to be `you` and then overwrites it if you have provided a name. The second line just prints it out for you.

That won't help if the user supplies an empty name (as with `script.sh ""`) so you may instead want to just check the variable itself rather than the count:

```
other="you"; [[ -n "$1" ]] && other="$1"
echo "One for ${other}, one for me."
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the second one totally helped

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "One for ${1:-you}, one for me."
```

When `$1` is null or unset, then place `you` there.

For reference see [bash manual shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Alternatively, if you have zero arguments, you could set "default" ones.

```
if (($# == 0)); then
    set -- you
fi
echo "One for $1, one for me."
```

which is equivalent, because it will handle empty argument `$1=""` differently.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this one "echo "One for ${1:-you}, one for me." but it didn't work, I used a different aproach. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dieguin, that *should* have worked, what output did you get?

Comment: I ran it in a test file, when was empty the option worked but when there was an input, the echo didn't work.